# Installing torchvision from source libavcodec/avcodec.h not found

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to install torchvision from source, was able to get pytorch installed (needed it from source to use GPU) and now can't get torchvision to work.

I am getting the following error when I run the setup.py:

> C:\Users\hoski\vision\torchvision\csrc\cpu\decoder\defs.h(11): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libavcodec/avcodec.h': No such file or directory
>   error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I downloaded the source for ffmpeg and added it to my path, and I checked the libavcodec folder and the file is there, it just isn't seeing it I guess?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try change `has_ffmpeg = ffmpeg_exe is not None` in Setup.py `to has_ffmpeg = False`

Comment: Should that be `False` and not `Flase`?